# How to read URL starting with view-source in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to read following URL and it should save the content available in the page to Text file.

I use below code to read page source:

```
string address = "view-source:http://stackoverflow.com/";  //any web site url

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var Text= wc.DownloadString(address);            
}
```

But it is throwing exception "The URI prefix is not recognized."

Any Help Would be Appreciate.

Thanks! in advance.

Comment: When you use http://stackoverflow.com and DownLoadString, are you not getting the HTML markup you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a feature of Chrome by prepending `"view-source:"` to that url.  The `WebClient` class probably doesn't know *anything* about that feature.  It's complaining about the "URI prefix" being unrecognized.  That's the `"view-source:"` portion of your string.

So, remove that part of the URL and you will have a valid url.

```
string userInput = "view-source:http://stackoverflow.com/";
string address = userInput.Replace("view-source:", "");
```

Note: this may produce different results for web apps that provide additional content after javascript has been run and interpreted.  You might not ultimately get what you want.

Edit: after your comment, it sounds like you want to *remove* the possibility of the url starting with `"view-source:"` which I have reflected in the answer.

Just in case you're looking for the "post javascript" source.  There's a [project on github](https://github.com/rguerra712/source-as-a-service) that offers this feature but I've never used it. I only know about it because it's maintained by a guy I work with.

You can also find a working example [in this repl](https://repl.it/@clarkitect/DaringEasygoingWorkplaces)

Comment: I want to read URL starting with "view-source:". Is there any way to read this sort of url?